# Supabase Dashboard error (self-hosting): "Failed to create user: User not allowed", when i try to create a new user

Tags: supabase, supabase-js, supabase-py

When I try to create a new user I receive the following error, does anyone know why it happens?
I'm new to supabase and don't have much experience.

[supabase dashboard error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOcKp.png)

In the .env file, the only relevant thing that I modified was the password of POSGREST_PASSWORD, JWT_SECRET, ANON_KEY and SERVICE_ROLE_KEY following the supabase documentation.

I also tried restarting the docker service to see if it was some supabase error but it didn't work either.